# DataContract vs Serializable -- Do either really matter if you want to serialize as efficient (custom binary) as possible?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract

Basically, if I mark my classes as `[DataContract]` can I still write my own serializer that extends from XmlObjectSerializer that returns a binary the same way as I could if I did `[Serializable]`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but remember that the serializer, if inheriting from `XmlObjectSerializer` will have to deal with XML. Which XML writer / reader you use will determine whether you're using a binary representation or not. One "binary" XML reader/writer is the one created by `XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader` and `XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter`.

The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/29/wcf-extensibility-icontractbehavior.aspx has a sample which shows a custom XmlObjectSerializer which, if used with a binary XML writer, can serialize objects to a fairly small size.